# After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I cannot find settings anywhere; how can I bring it back?

Tags: 20.04, system-settings, gnome-control-center

I tried the Gnome Command Center and also install command but I am getting this error as shown in the picture.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Can't find settings in search function also

[image: no results in gnome shell search]

Settings also not available in system tray menu

[[image: no settings in tray]

After [Scott told me](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239845/527764) the steps which may fix this issue I tried it on terminal and here is the history or log.

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install

[sudo] password for incredibletwins: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu focal 
InRelease
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu bionic 
InRelease
Fetched 401 kB in 8s (48.4 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
```

---

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt-get install libsnmp35

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsnmp35 : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt-get install sane-utils

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sane-utils : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.27)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ sudo apt-get reinstall gnome-control- 
center gnome-settings-daemon

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be 
installed
       Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by 
held packages.
```

---

```
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$ dpkg -l | grep libsnmp35
incredibletwins@incredibletwins:~$
```

What else can I try?

Comment: refresh page and run what I suggest ... namely `dpkg -l | grep libsnmp`   notice its leaving off specific ver  35

Answer (score 1):

You have certainly installed external packages.

try to run this command to see conflicting dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install gnome-control-center
```

in my case, I had installed oibaf/graphics-drivers for nvidia gpu.

remove it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository –remove ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

see the installed packages of "oibaf".

```
sudo dpkg --list |grep oibaf |awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d:
```

in my case I had to reinstall the packages for the "focal" version

```
sudo apt install debhelper/focal libclang1-10/focal libdebhelper-perl/focal libdrm-amdgpu1/focal libdrm-amdgpu1/focal libdrm-common/focal libdrm-intel1/focal libdrm-intel1/focal libdrm-nouveau2/focal libdrm-nouveau2/focal libdrm-radeon1/focal libdrm-radeon1/focal libdrm2/focal libdrm2/focal libegl-mesa0/focal libegl1-mesa/focal libgbm1/focal libgl1-mesa-dri/focal libgl1-mesa-dri/focal libgl1-mesa-glx/focal libgl1-mesa-glx/focal libglapi-mesa/focal libglapi-mesa/focal libglx-mesa0/focal libglx-mesa0/focal libllvm10/focal libllvm10/focal libwayland-egl1-mesa/focal libxatracker2/focal mesa-va-drivers/focal mesa-vdpau-drivers/focal mesa-vulkan-drivers/focal
```

and remove all package *oibaf*.

reboot your pc and install gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon.

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your sane-utils, check if you have gnome-control-center, gnome-settings-daemon, gnome-settings-common.

`dpkg -l | grep sane-utils`

`dpkg -l | grep gnome-control`

`dpkg -l | grep gnome-settings`

Then install the newest `sane-utils` package firstly, later reinstall `gnome-control-center`, `gnome-settings-daemon` and `gnome-settings-daemon-common`.

`apt-get install sane-utils`

`apt-get reinstall gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon`

[search packages as you need](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/)

Comment: Plz check question again.

i am not able to still find my settings anywhere.

Comment: I'd suggest that when there are issues like > Depends: xxx, check xxx firstly with `dpkg -l | grep xxx`, if no, then  install or reinstall it at first.

Answer (score 0):

issue this

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt-get install libsnmp35

sudo apt-get install sane-utils

sudo apt-get reinstall gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon
```

remain calm this is certainly fixable ... as the other answer suggests in order for us to help you if this fails to fix it update your question and show current errors

typically your error means you have an application installed which needs the old version of a package which prevents installing a newer version of that package ( libsnmp35 )   so possible solution is to remove that offending application and install the held package

after running below if it shows that package has an earlier release installed then we might want to remove that package which will uninstall all applications using it which will free up system to allow above commands to run successfully

update your question and show output of running

```
dpkg -l | grep libsnmp
```

Comment: I updated the question kindly take a look please.

Comment: kindly take a look again.

Comment: well that's the thing i don't know how to find that held package and to remove it,
I tried using aptitude but couldn't get my head around it.
what do u have next in mind?

Comment: did you run   `dpkg -l | grep libsnmp`   ????    notice there is no 35   ...  if it shows an earlier release then you want to remove that earlier release so show output of running this in your question

Answer (score 0):

Guys, I appreciate you all trying,
I tried many steps suggested by you and others too,
and for that I am grateful,

But as the problem was severe as without settings I couldn't turn on-off wifi or change network I had to install ubuntu 20.04 again erasing the old one.
and now it works perfectly,

so any user like me out there having the same problem I urge you to follow the steps given in this thread first and still if it doesn't work then you can do what I did but make sure you backup everything and remember your ubuntu sign-on passwords and other login credentials.

Thanks once again.
Over & Out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution was to use Aptitude. See this [post](https://leonrichter.de/posts/gnome_control_center_bug/).

```sh
$ sudo aptitude install gnome-control-center
```

Aptitude does not give up so quickly and offers more options in dealing with dependencies. It could solve the dependency conflict.